# optimize onScroll event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple horizontal scroll div.

```
function Horizontal(){
  const [now, setNow] = React.useState(0);
  function handleScroll(e){
    const { scrollLeft } = e.currentTarget;
    setNow(scrollLeft);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <p>{now}px</p>
      <div width={3000} height={80} onScroll={handleScroll}>
        {...}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is an example code and it works well.

but I realize `scrollLeft` causes `reflow`.

so, I want to optimize it as well as possible.

Please leave advice if you have any.

Comment: Maybe if you move `<p>{now}</p>` to a different component, and move this `useState` to a parent node and use `memo` on `Horizontal`?

Comment: it is just an example, so real code has a more complex structure.

Comment: Okay, but how is your original code different in a way that you can't make these changes?